# How to generate a random number with a specific amount of digits?

Tags: python, random

Let's say I need a 3-digit number, so it would be something like:

```
>>> random(3)
563

or

>>> random(5)
26748
>> random(2)
56
```

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can use either of [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) or [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange). So to get a random 3-digit number:

```
from random import randint, randrange

randint(100, 999)     # randint is inclusive at both ends
randrange(100, 1000)  # randrange is exclusive at the stop
```

<sup>* Assuming you really meant three digits, rather than "up to three digits".</sup>

---

To use an arbitrary number of digits:

```
from random import randint

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)
    
print random_with_N_digits(2)
print random_with_N_digits(3)
print random_with_N_digits(4)
```

Output:

```
33
124
5127
```

Comment: With this solution, you will eliminate 10**(n-1) numbers from your random pool

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu: Yes, that's why I said *assuming you really meant three digits, rather than "up to three digits".*

Comment: 037 it's a 3 digit number, smaller than 100 :). That's what I meant. But yeah, for a non-lottery application, your solution is just fine ;)

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu How can this snipet give you a result of 037??? it's a randint from (100 to 1000) if n ==3

Comment: @moldovean Read from the top :). I meant I wanted that number and this solution will not give you numbers up to that number of digits but rather of exactly that number of digits. It was my bad, I missed the clause in the parenthesis.

Comment: This really should just be random.randit(0,999)
Otherwize you can have "909" and "990" but not "099".

Comment: @J.J: Yes, that's why I said *assuming you really meant three digits, rather than "up to three digits"*.  Please read the previous comments.

Comment: @J.J: Up to three digits is easier `'{:03}'.format(random.randrange(0, 10**n))`.

Comment: Also possible is `"".join([str(randint(0, 9)) for i in range(n)])` or something to this degree.

Answer (score 57):

If you want it as a string (for example, a 10-digit phone number) you can use this:

```
n = 10
''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, n)])
```

Comment: ''.join(str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(n))

Answer (score 28):

If you need a 3 digit number and want 001-099 to be valid numbers you should still use randrange/randint as it is quicker than alternatives. Just add the neccessary preceding zeros when converting to a string.

```
import random
num = random.randrange(1, 10**3)
# using format
num_with_zeros = '{:03}'.format(num)
# using string's zfill
num_with_zeros = str(num).zfill(3)
```

Alternatively if you don't want to save the random number as an int you can just do it as a oneliner:

```
'{:03}'.format(random.randrange(1, 10**3))
```

python 3.6+ only oneliner:

```
f'{random.randrange(1, 10**3):03}'
```

Example outputs of the above are:

- '026'
- '255'
- '512'

Implemented as a function that can support any length of digits not just 3:

```
import random

def n_len_rand(len_, floor=1):
    top = 10**len_
    if floor > top:
        raise ValueError(f"Floor '{floor}' must be less than requested top '{top}'")
    return f'{random.randrange(floor, top):0{len_}}'
```

Answer (score 7):

You could write yourself a little function to do what you want:

```
import random
def randomDigits(digits):
    lower = 10**(digits-1)
    upper = 10**digits - 1
    return random.randint(lower, upper)
```

Basically, `10**(digits-1)` gives you the smallest {digit}-digit number, and `10**digits - 1` gives you the largest {digit}-digit number (which happens to be the smallest {digit+1}-digit number minus 1!). Then we just take a random integer from that range.

Answer (score 6):

Does 0 count as a possible first digit? If so, then you need `random.randint(0,10**n-1)`. If not, `random.randint(10**(n-1),10**n-1)`. And if zero is *never* allowed, then you'll have to explicitly reject numbers with a zero in them, or draw `n` `random.randint(1,9)` numbers.

Aside: it is interesting that `randint(a,b)` uses somewhat non-pythonic "indexing" to get a random number `a <= n <= b`. One might have expected it to work like `range`, and produce a random number `a <= n < b`. (Note the closed upper interval.)

Given the responses in the comments about `randrange`, note that these can be replaced with the cleaner `random.randrange(0,10**n)`, `random.randrange(10**(n-1),10**n)` and `random.randrange(1,10)`.

Comment: @Andrew: `a <= n <= b` surprised me too.  I resent having to put that extra `-1` in my code.  :-)

Comment: @Andrew - funnily enough, the Python code for `randint` (it's in Lib/random.py) actually just calls `randrange(a, b+1)`!

Answer (score 6):

This solution doesn't include 0 as the starting integer.

```
import random

fixed_digits = 6 

print(random.randrange(111111, 999999, fixed_digits))

out:
271533
```

If 0 doesn't matter for you as a starting integer, Then you can use 000001 or 100000 as a start range.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function who consumes an list of int, transforms in string to concatenate and cast do int again, something like this:

```
import random

def generate_random_number(length):
    return int(''.join([str(random.randint(0,10)) for _ in range(length)]))
```

Comment: its not generating numbers of a particular length :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use this

```
from string import digits
import random

verify_code = ''.join(random.choice(digits) for i in range(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the answer of RichieHindle, however I liked the question as an exercise. Here's a brute force implementation using strings:)

```
import random
first = random.randint(1,9)
first = str(first)
n = 5

nrs = [str(random.randrange(10)) for i in range(n-1)]
for i in range(len(nrs))    :
    first += str(nrs[i])

print str(first)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html), does it not seem that the sample() method is appropriate for this purpose?

```
import random

def random_digits(n):
    num = range(0, 10)
    lst = random.sample(num, n)
    print str(lst).strip('[]')
```

Output:

```
>>>random_digits(5)
2, 5, 1, 0, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I see many solutions throughout the years. here is my suggestion for a function that creates an n digits random string with default 6.

```
from random import randint

def OTP(n=6):
    n = 1 if n< 1 else n
    return randint(int("1"*n), int("9"*n))
```

of course you can change "1"*n to whatever you want the start to be.