# generate a random number with fixed length

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random number with in two range, and i want it to have fixed length. I don't want to limit the range as offered i
[How to generate random number with the specific length in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673385/how-to-generate-random-number-with-the-specific-length-in-python)

as following: [10] -> [00010]

[36554] ->[36554]

[554] -> [00554]

Could you guide me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import random
'{0:05}'.format(random.randint(1, 100000))
```

creates fixed length string representation of a random number like `'00554'`.