# How do I generate random numbers in Dart?

Tags: random, dart

How do I generate random numbers using Dart?

Comment: How do you know they're bad numbers? The thing about random is that you can never really tell... http://i46.tinypic.com/2vw7237.gif

Comment: Trust me, you'd know they are bad if you used dart:core Math. :)  Here's the bug: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=499

Comment: If you want to know whether your random numbers are bad, use my ChiSquare library to find out: https://github.com/kaisellgren/ChiSquare

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Use [`Random`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/Random-class.html) class from `dart:math`:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  var rng = Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print(rng.nextInt(100));
  }
}
```

This code was tested with the Dart VM and dart2js, as of the time of this writing.

Comment: You are better off reading `/dev/urandom` with the `File` class if you want cryptographically strong random numbers.

Comment: How about negative random numbers (doubles)?
I'm trying to implement a randomRange method that would generate for example from -0.8 to 0.9  ... the result would be for example -0.32

Comment: @just_a_dude that sounds like a perfect question for stackoverflow. Consider creating a new question :)

Comment: method that would generate for example from -0.8 to 0.9 is simple. You just need to map values. Your range is 0.8+0.9= 1,7. So if you put rng.nextInt(1700) you will get number between 0 and 1700. Divide by 100 and reduce -0,8. Meaning yourRnd = rng.nextInt(1700)/100.0-0.8. There are more options you can use like not even using nextInt but rather double 0-1, miltiplied by 1,7 and shifted -0.8

Comment: `new Random.secure()` for cryptographically strong random numbers from dart 1.1.4

Answer (score 159):

You can achieve it via `Random` class object `random.nextInt(max)`, which is in `dart:math` library. The `nextInt()` method requires a max limit. The random number starts from `0` and the max limit itself is exclusive.

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100); // from 0 upto 99 included
```

If you want to add the min limit, add the min limit to the result

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(90) + 10; // from 10 upto 99 included
```

Answer (score 42):

try this, you can control the **min/max** value :

*NOTE that you need to import dart math library.*

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  
  int random(int min, int max) {
    return min + Random().nextInt(max - min);
  }

  print(random(5, 20)); // Output : 19, 5, 15.. (5 -> 19, 20 is not included)
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Here's a snippet for generating a list of random numbers

```
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var rng = new Random();
  var l = new List.generate(12, (_) => rng.nextInt(100));
}
```

This will generate a list of 12 integers from 0 to 99 (inclusive).

Answer (score 27):

A secure random API was just added to `dart:math`

```
new Random.secure()
```

> `dart:math`
>     `Random` added a `secure` constructor returning a cryptographically secure
>     random generator which reads from the entropy source provided by the
>     embedder for every generated random value.

which delegates to `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` in the browser and to the OS (like `urandom` on the server)

Comment: This new API is available in 1.14-dev or greater.

Answer (score 19):

If you need **cryptographically-secure** random numbers (e.g. for encryption), and you're in a browser, you can use the [DOM cryptography API](http://api.dartlang.org/html/Crypto.html):

```
int random() {
  final ary = new Int32Array(1);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(ary);
  return ary[0];
}
```

This works in Dartium, Chrome, and Firefox, but likely not in other browsers as this is an experimental API.

Answer (score 9):

Let me answer this question with a practical example in the form of a simple dice rolling app that calls 1 of 6 dice face images randomly to the screen when tapped.

first declare a variable that generates random numbers (don't forget to import dart.math). Then declare a variable that parses the initial random number within constraints between 1 and 6 as an Integer.

Both variables are static private in order to be initialized once.This is is not a huge deal but would be good practice if you had to initialize a whole bunch of random numbers.

```
static var _random = new Random();
static var _diceface = _random.nextInt(6) +1 ;
```

Now create a Gesture detection widget with a ClipRRect as a child to return one of the six dice face images to the screen when tapped.

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _diceface = _random.nextInt(6) +1 ;
            });
          },
          child: ClipRRect(
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.8),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/diceface$_diceface.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
          )
        ),
```

A new random number is generated each time you tap the screen and that number is referenced to select which dice face image is chosen.

[Dice rolling app using random numbers in dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPS8N.gif)

Comment: _random should be _rnd or vice versa

Answer (score 8):

its worked for me  `new Random().nextInt(100); // MAX = number`

it will give 0 to 99 random number

Eample::

```
import 'dart:math';
int MAX = 100;
print(new Random().nextInt(MAX));`
```

Answer (score 7):

Not able to comment because I just created this account, but I wanted to make sure to point out that @eggrobot78's solution works, but it is exclusive in dart so it doesn't include the last number. If you change the last line to "r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1);", then it should include the last number as well.

Explanation:

```
max = 5;
min = 3;
Random rnd = new Random();
r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
//max - min is 2
//nextInt is exclusive so nextInt will return 0 through 1
//3 is added so the line will give a number between 3 and 4
//if you add the "+ 1" then it will return a number between 3 and 5
```

Answer (score 6):

you can generate by simply in this way
there is a class named Random();

you can use that and genrate random numbers

```
Random objectname = Random();
int number = objectname.nextInt(100);
// it will generate random number within 100.
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution could be using the following code [DRandom](https://github.com/financeCoding/DRandom/blob/master/DRandom.dart). This class should be used with a seed. It provides a familiar interface to what you would expect in .NET, it was ported from mono's Random.cs. This code may not be cryptography safe and has not been statistically tested.

Comment: I've used DRandom before.  Good lib!

Answer (score 3):

Just wrote this little class for generating **Normal** Random numbers...  it was a decent starting point for the checking I need to do.  (These sets will distribute on a "bell" shaped
curve.)  The seed will be set randomly, but if you want to be able to re-generate a set you can just pass some specific seed and the same set will generate.

Have fun...

```
class RandomNormal {
  num     _min, _max,  _sum;
  int     _nEle, _seed, _hLim;
  Random  _random;
  List    _rNAr;

  //getter
  List get randomNumberAr => _rNAr;

  num _randomN() {
    int r0 = _random.nextInt(_hLim);
    int r1 = _random.nextInt(_hLim);
    int r2 = _random.nextInt(_hLim);
    int r3 = _random.nextInt(_hLim);

    num rslt = _min + (r0 + r1 + r2 + r3) / 4000.0;  //Add the OS back in...
    _sum += rslt; //#DEBUG ONLY
    return( rslt );
  }

  RandomNormal(this._nEle, this._min, this._max, [this._seed = null]) {
    if (_seed == null ) {
      Random r = new Random();
      _seed    = r.nextInt(1000);
    }
    _hLim   = (_max - _min).ceil() * 1000;
    _random = new Random(_seed);
    _rNAr   = [];
    _sum    = 0;//#DEBUG ONLY

    h2("RandomNormal with k: ${_nEle}, Seed: ${_seed}, Min: ${_min}, Max: ${_max}");//#DEBUG ONLY
    for(int n = 0; n < _nEle; n++ ){
      num randomN = _randomN();
      //p("randomN  = ${randomN}");
      LIST_add( _rNAr, randomN );
    }

    h3("Mean = ${_sum/_nEle}");//#DEBUG ONLY
  }
}


new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
new RandomNormal(1000, 80, 120);
```

Then you can just use it like this to check the mean of sets of 1000 nums generated between a low and high limit.   The values are stored in the class so they can be accessed after instantiation.

_swarmii

Answer (score 3):

For me the easiest way is to do:

```
import 'dart:math';
Random rnd = new Random();
r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
//where min and max should be specified.
```

Thanks to @adam-singer explanation in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318207/how-to-get-a-random-number-from-range-in-dart)

Answer (score 3):

This method generates random integer. Both minimum and maximum are inclusive.

Make sure you add this line to your file: `import 'dart:math';` Then you can add and use this method:

```
int randomInt(int min, int max) {
return Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

So if you call `randomInt(-10,10)` it will return a number between -10 and 10 (including -10 and 10).

Answer (score 2):

Use Dart Generators, that is used to produce a sequence of number or values.

```
 main(){ 
       print("Sequence Number");
       oddnum(10).forEach(print);
     }
    Iterable<int> oddnum(int num) sync*{
     int k=num;
     while(k>=0){
       if(k%2==1){
        yield k;
       }
      k--;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use class Random() from 'dart:math' library.

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int max = 10;
  int RandomNumber = Random().nextInt(max);
  print(RandomNumber);
}
```

This should generate and print a random number from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2):

one line solution you can directly call all the functions with constructor as well.

```
import 'dart:math';

print(Random().nextInt(100));
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {

  Random random = Random();
  int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
  print(randomNumber);

}
```

Change the number five for possible results you want

Answer (score 0):

To generate random double:

```
import 'dart:math';

print(Random().nextDouble());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code, to generate a random number with N digits:

```
import 'dart:math';

int random_with_N_digits(int n) {
        final start = pow(10, (n - 1));
        final end = pow(10, n) - 1;
        Random random = Random();
        final x = random.nextInt(end.toInt()) + start;
        
        return x.toInt();
      }
```

this code converted from [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673399/3241790).