# How to get a random number from range in dart?

Tags: dart

How does one get a random number within a range similar to c# Random.Next(int min, int max);

Comment: there should be  dart method for that!

Comment: @Gero There is an open issue for it: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/6524. Perhaps everyone reading this can add a +1 to show it would be helpful.

Answer (score 103):

```dart
import 'dart:math';

final _random = new Random();

/**
 * Generates a positive random integer uniformly distributed on the range
 * from [min], inclusive, to [max], exclusive.
 */
int next(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);
```

Answer (score 48):

You can achieve it via `Random` class object `random.nextInt(max)` . The `nextInt()` method requires a max limit. The random number starts from `0` and the max limit itself is exclusive.

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100); // from 0 upto 99 included
```

If you want to add the min limit, add the min limit to the result

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(90) + 10; // from 10 upto 99 included
```

Comment: adding any number to the `Random().nextInt(max)` also increase the random number by that. So it doesn't fall under the range. For example, if your `max = 20` and you want a range of `15 to 20` it won't happen. However you will get `range of 15 to 35`. because of + 15 at random number.

Comment: @DhananjayGavali you don't add the 10 or 20 to the max value. The trick is here, you want a number in the range of `min = 10` to `max = 100` get your random number as `c = max -  min` which happens to be 90.`randomNumber = random.nextInt(90)` then add the min value to your random value as `randomNumber = random.next(90) + 10`

Answer (score 46):

Range can be found with a simple formula as follows

```
Random rnd;
int min = 5;
int max = 10;
rnd = new Random();
r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
print("$r is in the range of $min and $max");
```

Answer (score 28):

This is really late, but this for anyone who still has the question.

The easiest way to get a random number between a min and a max is the following :

```
import 'dart:math';

int max = 10;

int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(max) + 1;
```

The math module in dart has a function called nextInt. This will return an integer from 0 (including 0 ) to max - 1 ( exluding max ). I want a number 1 to 10, hence I add 1 to the nextInt result.

Comment: adding any number to the `Random().nextInt(max)` also increase the random number by that. So it doesn't fall under the range. For example, if your `max = 20` and you want a range of `15 to 20` it won't happen. However you will get `range of 15 to 35`. because of + 15 at random number.

Answer (score 6):

Generates a random integer uniformly distributed in the
range from [min] to [max], both inclusive.

```
int nextInt(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt((max + 1) - min);
```

Answer (score 5):

**To Generate a random positive integer between a given range**:

```
final _random = new Random();

// from MIN(inclusive), to MAX(exclusive).
int randomBetween(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);

// from MIN(inclusive), to MAX(inclusive).
int randomBetween(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt((max+1) - min);

// from MIN(exclusive), to MAX(exclusive).
int randomBetween(int min, int max) => (min+1) + _random.nextInt(max - (min+1));
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved exactly as you intended by creating extension on `int` to get random int value. For example:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

extension RandomInt on int {
  static int generate({int min = 0, @required int max}) {
    final _random = Random();
    return min + _random.nextInt(max - min);
  }
}
```

And you can use this in your code like so:

```
List<int> rands = [];
for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
  rands.add(RandomInt.generate(max: 50));
}
```

Note that static extension methods can't be called on type itself (e.g. `int.generate(min:10, max:20)`), but instead you have to use extension name itself, in this example `RandomInt`. For detailed discussion, [read here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723).

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'dart:math';

Random rnd = new Random();
// Define min and max value
int min = 1, max = 10;
//Getting range
int num = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
print("$num is in the range of $min and $max");
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random double within a range, multiply a random int with a random double.

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int min = 1, max = 10;
double num = (min + random.nextInt(max - min)) * random.nextDouble();
```

Comment: this will generate a double between 0 and the int generated randomly (so lower than your min)

Comment: This would be the proper way to achieve that
`min + ((max - min) * Random().nextDouble());`
and both min / max can be double in that case

Answer (score 1):

When I was making a Tetris game, I had to rotate the x-axis. For this, I wrote the following codes.
I hope it will be useful for you too:

```
Random rnd = Random();
int min = 0;
int max = 23;
class Block {
  int x = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way of doing this is to use the nextInt method within Random:

```
// Random 50 to 100:
int min = 50;
int max = 100;
int selection = min + (Random(1).nextInt(max-min));
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-math/Random-class.html

Comment: Downvoted for several reasons. Firstly, this answer is fundamentally no different to the highest voted answer from 6 years ago. Secondly, you are seeding the random generated with `1` every time. This means your code example will always produce the same result!