# flutter - How to auto scroll to index with dynamic height programmatically

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-layout

According to Flutter's [issue here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319) , The **Auto-Scroll to Index** where each cell/item has **dynamic height** is currently not supported. I have tried another solution but no works.

so, What's a temporary solution to make `ListView` with `AutoScroll` for dynamic height?

Any Idea?

Comment: If _every_ item in the list has a completely random height (dynamically) and you want to, let's say, scroll to the item N when the view is rendered, you'll have to find the height/position of the `RenderObject` in a post frame that you want to jump to, and then you'll should be fine in auto scrolling to there.

Comment: If you're scrolling to an item that has been rendered before, could you cache it's position and scroll to the position rather than its index? Also, any changes to the list would invalidate all items' positions after it.

Answer (score 12):

### Your question

> so, What's a temporary solution to make ListView with AutoScroll for dynamic height?

### Screen Record

[image]

### solution

scroll-to-index package

> This package provides the scroll to index mechanism for fixed/variable row height for Flutter scrollable widget.
>
> This is a widget level library, means you can use this mechanism inside any Flutter scrollable widget.

### Usage

pubspec.yaml

```
 scroll_to_index: any
```

Example From [quire-io/scroll-to-index: scroll to index with fixed/variable row height inside Flutter scrollable widget](https://github.com/quire-io/scroll-to-index)

#### Usage - Controller

```
controller.scrollToIndex(index, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin)
```

#### Usage - ListView

```
ListView(
scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
controller: controller,
children: randomList.map<Widget>((data) {
    final index = data[0];
    final height = data[1];
    return AutoScrollTag(
    key: ValueKey(index),
    controller: controller,
    index: index,
    child: Text('index: $index, height: $height'),
    highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
    );
}).toList(),
)
```

### Extra anunixercoder  asked

> Is this for finite or infinite list ?

Using  **ListView.builder** to simulate an infinite list

```
    ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
    controller: controller,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: _getRow(i, (min + rnd.nextInt(max - min)).toDouble()),
    ),
```

It got 18 right of 22 tries , about (81%) or **near to it**

### Screen Record

[image]

so it not suported 100%

### Ref :

- [scroll_to_index | Flutter Package](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index#-readme-tab-)
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quire-io/scroll-to-index/master/example/lib/main.dart
- [How to get a random number from range in dart? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318207/how-to-get-a-random-number-from-range-in-dart)

### 1st screen record code

```
//Copyright (C) 2019 Potix Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
//History: Tue Apr 24 09:29 CST 2019
// Author: Jerry Chen

import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll To Index Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Scroll To Index Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const maxCount = 100;
  final random = math.Random();
  final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;

  AutoScrollController controller;
  List<List<int>> randomList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AutoScrollController(
      viewportBoundaryGetter: () => Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
      axis: scrollDirection
    );
    randomList = List.generate(maxCount, (index) => <int>[index, (1000 * random.nextDouble()).toInt()]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
        controller: controller,
        children: randomList.map<Widget>((data) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: _getRow(data[0], math.max(data[1].toDouble(), 50.0)),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _scrollToIndex,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text(counter.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  int counter = -1;
  Future _scrollToIndex() async {
    setState(() {
      counter++;

      if (counter >= maxCount)
        counter = 0;
    });

    await controller.scrollToIndex(counter, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin);
    controller.highlight(counter);
  }

  Widget _getRow(int index, double height) {
    return _wrapScrollTag(
      index: index,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            width: 4
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
        ),
        child: Text('index: $index, height: $height'),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _wrapScrollTag({int index, Widget child})
  => AutoScrollTag(
    key: ValueKey(index),
    controller: controller,
    index: index,
    child: child,
    highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
  );
}
```

### 2nd screen record  code :

```
//Copyright (C) 2019 Potix Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
//History: Tue Apr 24 09:29 CST 2019
// Author: Jerry Chen

import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll To Index Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Scroll To Index Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;
  var rnd = math.Random();
  int min = 50;
  int max = 200;
  AutoScrollController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AutoScrollController(
        viewportBoundaryGetter: () =>
            Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
        axis: scrollDirection);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: _getRow(i, (min + rnd.nextInt(max - min)).toDouble()),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _scrollToIndex,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text(counter.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  int counter = -1;
  Future _scrollToIndex() async {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });

    await controller.scrollToIndex(counter,
        preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin);
    controller.highlight(counter);
  }

  Widget _getRow(int index, double height) {
    return _wrapScrollTag(
        index: index,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          height: height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 4),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          child: Text('index: $index, height: $height'),
        ));
  }

  Widget _wrapScrollTag({int index, Widget child}) => AutoScrollTag(
        key: ValueKey(index),
        controller: controller,
        index: index,
        child: child,
        highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
      );
}
```

Comment: Is this for `finite` or `infinite` list ?

Comment: @anunixercoder , finite but no infinite , check the Answer for more details

Comment: Hi, Can i use `ListView.builder` for finite list ?

Comment: This solves for a list with irregular height but it does not solve for a list with real dynamic height (a.k.a height changes over time). I have a bloc that handles each row's data. When it fetches the data then the row will expand accordingly. Now I have no idea how to scroll to a certain index accurately. It is always off.

Answer (score 1):

This package might be the one you are looking for. You can assign id for each widget and enable an animation just like tags in HTML.

https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_id

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_id/scroll_to_id.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final ScrollToId scrollToId = ScrollToId();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll to ID',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Scroll to ID'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            InteractiveScrollViewer(
              scrollToId: scrollToId,
              children: [
                ScrollContent(
                  id: '1',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 600,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                ScrollContent(
                  id: '2',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 800,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                ScrollContent(
                  id: '3',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
                ScrollContent(
                  id: '4',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 700,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      scrollToId.scroll(id: '1');
                    },
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text('2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      scrollToId.scroll(id: '2');
                    },
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text('3', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      scrollToId.scroll(id: '3');
                    },
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Text('4', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      scrollToId.scroll(id: '4');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How observe current offset index?

```
    controller.addListener(() {
      AutoScrollTagState sts = controller.tagMap[0];
      print(sts);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin. [scroll_loop_auto_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_loop_auto_scroll)

This plugin automatically scrolls the custom child widget to an infinite loop.

and you can give dynamic size items.

Features #

- Infinite Auto Scroll
- Custom child widgets
- Delay after every round
- Custom scroll direction
- Specifying custom durations and gap