# How to run code after some random/dynamic delay in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to run a function with some random/dynamic delay. [`Future.delayed`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) can help in this but it took time as `const`. I am unable to pass an expression or non `const` value as time. Is there any way to make it parameterise or random? So with each call delay will be different.

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: needRandomNumberHere), () {
    // code will be here
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use any variable, like others have shown here.

You are misunderstanding the `const` in this context.
There is **no way** to **force** `const` in Dart - it is always optional. You can only force yourself to use `const` by declaring it that way.

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 42), () {
    // code will be here
});
// does the exact same as:
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 42), () {
    // code will be here
});
```

As you can tell, `const` is optional.

This means that the following will just work fine:

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(420)), () {
    // code will be here
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Once I remove `const` keyword its work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dart's [Random class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-math/Random-class.html):

> int nextInt(int max)
>
> Generates a non-negative random integer uniformly distributed in the range from 0, inclusive, to max, exclusive.

So, in your code:

```
import 'dart:math';
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(3000)), () {
    // code will be here
});
```

will run the code after a random time between 0 and 3000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
Timer? timer;
void startTimerRandomly() {
var random = Random();
var randomDuration = Duration(seconds: random.nextInt(10));
timer?.cancel();
timer=  Timer.periodic(
  randomDuration,
  (Timer timer) {
    if (mounted) {
       startTimerRandomly();
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
    
      }
    }
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674820/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-dart) to see how to generate random numbers in dart. What you can do is generate a random number and then pass it to the `milliseconds` field or even the `seconds` in the `Duration`.

Comment: Abba.m generating random number is not a issue. Actually, duration accept `const` only and random is not a `const`.

Comment: As clarified in the answer by creativecreatorormaybenot, the const is actually optional