# How to generate a 15 digits number in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in my project i have shipments, I want to generate a random number of 15 digits to be used to track. How to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random numbers in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674820/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer `Random` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/Random-class.html)

```
import 'dart:math';
main(){
  var number ="";
  var randomnumber=  Random();
   //chnage i < 15 on your digits need 
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  number = number + randomnumber.nextInt(9).toString();
  }
  print(number);
}
```

Your output : `353572614254280`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:math';
Random random = new Random();
int rNumber = random.nextInt(10^15); // 15 digits (0 to 999999999999999)
int rNumber2 = random.nextInt(10^15) + 10^14; // 100000000000000 to 999999999999999
```

Comment: Nice answer, but `10^15` should be `pow(10, 15)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if there is any "optimal" way to do that but you can try the following using math library of dart.

```
  String generate15Digits(){
    var rng = Random();
    String generatedNumber = '';
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
      generatedNumber += (rng.nextInt(9)+1).toString();
    
    }
  
    return generatedNumber;
}
```

Also do keep in mind that the first digit will never be zero (because we are adding 1 to every digit), and you need to add `import 'dart:math'` library