# Flutter generate number

Tags: flutter, code-generation, auto-generate

Is it possible for flutter to generate a random number, store them somewhere so that it doesn't generate the same number even if the app is restarted?
If yes, how is that done?

Comment: Can it simply store the random number in the local database? Then, when generating a new random number, it can check if it has already been generated and, if so, regenerate a new one.

Comment: I don't have a local database. I'm using Firebase as my backend

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The important thing about random numbers is that they are **random**. You don't care if a single number is the same provided that the sequence following it is different. One way that ultra long period RNGs fail is that they don't generate collisions often enough if you retain too many bits. Seeding an RNG with some hash of system time is one way to avoid exactly reproducible numbers if that is your intent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random numbers in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674820/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-dart)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't quite say it answers it directly. The problem is that user gets a randomly generated number which the user uses as his/her ID number. I don't know if it's possible for the generator can general the same number for different different people. That's what I wanted to find out

Comment: It sounds like you want to create an *account* for the user. When you store that, it undoubtedly has a (unique) account ID

Comment: You want unique tags not random numbers - there is a crucial difference! Choose a long period RNG and save the seed after each invocation. Or you could just add 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a number with `Random.nextInt(100)` 100 means generate a number between 0 to 100 randomly,
then use shareprefences to save that value

(Do not forget to add `import 'dart:math';` in your dependencies)