# Python: How to generate a 12-digit random number?

Tags: python

In Python, how to generate a 12-digit random number? Is there any function where we can specify a range like `random.range(12)`?

```
import random
random.randint()
```

The output should be a string with 12 digits in the range 0-9 (leading zeros allowed).

Comment: Leading zeroes allowed.Actually want it to show as  a phone number

Comment: That was a *crucial* detail to miss out. That makes what you want a *string*, not a number, for example.

Comment: random.randint(10,99\**9)
489504272299263615

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73061434/12201407 I've answered this here

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Whats wrong with a straightforward approach?

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(100000000000,999999999999)
544234865004L
```

And if you want it with leading zeros, you need a string.

```
>>> "%0.12d" % random.randint(0,999999999999)
'023432326286'
```

**Edit:**

My own solution to this problem would be something like this:

```
import random

def rand_x_digit_num(x, leading_zeroes=True):
    """Return an X digit number, leading_zeroes returns a string, otherwise int"""
    if not leading_zeroes:
        # wrap with str() for uniform results
        return random.randint(10**(x-1), 10**x-1)  
    else:
        if x > 6000:
            return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in xrange(x)])
        else:
            return '{0:0{x}d}'.format(random.randint(0, 10**x-1), x=x)
```

Testing Results:

```
>>> rand_x_digit_num(5)
'97225'
>>> rand_x_digit_num(5, False)
15470
>>> rand_x_digit_num(10)
'8273890244'
>>> rand_x_digit_num(10)
'0019234207'
>>> rand_x_digit_num(10, False)
9140630927L
```

Timing methods for speed:

```
def timer(x):
        s1 = datetime.now()
        a = ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in xrange(x)])
        e1 = datetime.now()
        s2 = datetime.now()
        b = str("%0." + str(x) + "d") % random.randint(0, 10**x-1)
        e2 = datetime.now()
        print "a took %s, b took %s" % (e1-s1, e2-s2)
```

Speed test results:

```
>>> timer(1000)
a took 0:00:00.002000, b took 0:00:00
>>> timer(10000)
a took 0:00:00.021000, b took 0:00:00.064000
>>> timer(100000)
a took 0:00:00.409000, b took 0:00:04.643000
>>> timer(6000)
a took 0:00:00.013000, b took 0:00:00.012000
>>> timer(2000)
a took 0:00:00.004000, b took 0:00:00.001000
```

What it tells us:

For any digit under around 6000 characters in length my method is faster - sometimes MUCH faster, but for larger numbers the method suggested by [arshajii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357341/a-r-s) looks better.

Comment: Oh God! Please use `10**11` and `10**12 -1`. Otherwise these numbers become very difficult to debug/maintain

Comment: of course i would never have crazy numbers like that in code, its just for the answer to make it clear what is going on. my solution would not look like that at all.

Comment: Your solution returns an int OR a string - that is not how you intended it to work, right? Good example why, at least sometimes, static typing has its advantages

Comment: @Argeman you are correct that it is intended, as you notice there is a parameter in the function i wrote `leading_zeroes=True` by default it returns strings, if you turn it off explicitly then you should know you will be getting int/long

Comment: Oh, okay, than you solution is correct. In my OPINION its very bad design to let a function return different datatypes if there is no VERY good reason.

Comment: @Argeman if you prefer the parameter could read "return_int" and be `False` by default, and then just have the if/else reversed.

Comment: You don't have to agree with my opinion of course, but it's still no good idea to have different datatypes returning in my opinion. But of course, with a name like "return_int" it is much more clear what will happen if i change the function call...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19898/discussion-between-argeman-and-inbar-rose)

Comment: Very elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 5):

Do `random.randrange(10**11, 10**12)`. It works like `randint` meets `range`

From the documentation:

```
randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, int=<type 'int'>, default=None, maxwidth=9007199254740992L) method of random.Random instance
    Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
    Do not supply the 'int', 'default', and 'maxwidth' arguments.
```

This is effectively like doing `random.choice(range(10**11, 10**12))` or `random.randint(10**1, 10**12-1)`. Since it conforms to the same syntax as `range()`, it's a lot more intuitive and cleaner than these two alternatives

If leading zeros are allowed:

```
"%012d" %random.randrange(10**12)
```

Comment: Why use `random.randrange(10**11, 10**12)` over `random.randint(10**11, 10**12)`?

Comment: @cmh: because `randrange()` does *not* include the endpoint. You'd have to use `random.randint(10**11, 10**12-1)` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah ok. Then why use `random.randrange(10**11, 10**12)` over `random.randint(10**11, 10**12 - 1)`?

Comment: `random.randint(a,b)` returns a random `int` from `[a, b]`, i.e. it sometimes returns `b` as well. `random.randrange(a,b)` returns a random `int` from `[a, b)`, and will therefore never return `b`. It's like calling `random.randint(10**1, 10**12-1)`

Comment: @cmh: the [implementation of `randint(a, b)`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l237) *uses* `randrange(a, b+1)` internally. Using `randrange()` directly means you save a stack push, it'll be a little faster.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: `randrange()` returns a single number too. The only difference between `randint()` and `randrange()` is that the end value is included in the first, excluded in the second method.

Answer (score 4):

Since leading zeros are allowed (by your comment), you could also use:

```
int(''.join(str(random.randint(0,9)) for _ in xrange(12)))
```

---

***EDIT***: Of course, if you want a *string*, you can just leave out the `int` part:

```
''.join(str(random.randint(0,9)) for _ in xrange(12))
```

This seems like the most straightforward way to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that:

```
import random

rnumber1 = random.randint(10**11, 10**12-1) # randint includes endpoint
rnumber2 = random.randrange(10**11, 10**12) # randrange does not

# useful if you want to generate some random string from your choice of characters
digits = "123456789"
digits_with_zero = digits + "0"

rnumber3 = random.choice(digits) + ''.join(random.choice(digits_with_zero) for _ in range(11))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

print random_with_N_digits(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but a library like [rstr](https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/) let's you generate random strings. With that all you would need is (leading 0 allowed):

```
import rstr
foo = rstr.digits(12)
```

Comment: Why use an external library where there's `random` baked into the distro?