# Create random string with a char + 2 numbers - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Two questions:

1. How to create a char+number random string. one char and 2 digit numbers 
   for example: `U12 OR W82`
2. How to create a random 5 digit number with no zero at the beginning: `02345 , 03243`

Comment: Please keep your posts to **one** question per post. Your question is not specific to Flask, so I removed that tag.

Comment: You state you want a random 5 digit number but *no zero* at the beginning, then show two examples of random numbers with a zero at the beginning.

Comment: And my standard response to any give-me-the-code question: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate of [How to generate random number with the specific length in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2673385), there are probably duplicates for the first part too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Anyhow there are some good people out there that could understand my question and answered it correctly without any confusion.

Comment: We want questions to be useful to not just you, but to others as well. Moreover, by asking two questions you make it *harder* for people to answer. What if they only know the answer to one of the questions, and someone else knows the answer to the other? What answer will you then pick as the 'best' one?

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
import random, string
"%c%02d" % (random.choice(string.uppercase), random.randint(0, 99))
```

2)

```
import random
random.randint(10000, 99999)
```

Comment: Should the second answer be `random.randint(10000,99999)`?

Comment: This is why we the OP should not ask 2 questions. One of your answers is wrong, the other is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the first one.
for #2 sometimes it's 4 digits because of the zero : 
`>>> random.randint(0, 99999)`
`4230`

Comment: Well, I understood the second part as originally being "up to 5 digits while not displaying the first digits", which comes naturally. And is now fixed.