# Start at 100 and count up till 999

Tags: python

So, this is for my assignment and I have to create a flight booking system. One of the requirements is that it should create 3 digit passenger code that does not start with zeros (e.g. 100 is the smallest acceptable value) and I have no idea how I can do it since I am a beginner and I just started to learn Python. I have made classes for Passenger, Flight, Seating Area so far because I just started on it today. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Start at 100 and count up?  Generate random numbers in the range 100 thru 999?  It's not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: You should post some amount of code for the section that you want help with, as well as what you have tried so far and where it is going wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how to count from 100 to 999 or are you asking how to generate random numbers between 100 and 999? Or both? In the meanwhile, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673385/how-to-generate-random-number-with-the-specific-length-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
import random

numbers = range(100,1000)  # 100..999

rand_num = random.choice( numbers )   # get a random number

random.shuffle( numbers )  # shuffle numbers in the random order
```

or do whatever else you like...

Answer (score 0):

I like list comprehension for making a list of 100 to 999:

flights = [i for i in range(100, 1000)]

For the random version, there is probably a better way, but Random.randint(x, y) creates a random in, inclusive of the endpoints:

from random import Random

rand = Random()

flight = rand.randint(100,999)

Hope this helps with your homework, but do try to understand the assignment and how the code works...lest you get wrecked on the final!