# how to make a number generator on loops and limit each repetition to a maximum of 100, so that the number of numbers generated is 100 numbers

Tags: python

how to make a number generator on loops and limit each repetition to a maximum of 100, so that the number of numbers generated is 100 numbers.

Example of the resulting number:

EE-02100500004848486527

EE-02100500004848486432

up to 100 numbers.

so here I want the last 4 numbers to be randomized

this is my code

```
for x in range(100):
    print("EE-02100500004848486527")
```

Comment: `print(*(f"EE-0210050000484848{randrange(1000, 10000)}" for _ in range(100)), sep="\n")` [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Comment: bro code that you write doesn't work

Comment: Bro(Sis), code I wrote [is working](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5WAeUCcnsrFVVCUmVeioaWRpuTqqmtgZGhgYGoABCYWIFgNV6hhoKNgCJLQtDIwSalVUkjLL1KIV8jMU4BIA@U0NXUUilMLbJVi8pQ0//8HAA) for sure. I guess you've forgotten `from random import randrange`. Btw, in code from link I've used some advance formatting `f"EE-0210050000484848{randrange(0, 10000):04d}"`

Comment: Ah my mistake, now the code is already running, oh yeah how to save the code into the txt file?

Comment: Use search, there're thousands of questions with accepted answers which could help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random number with a specific amount of digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673385/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
import random
with open("your_file.txt", "w") as f:
    for _ in range(100):
        f.write(f"EE-0210050000484848{random.randint(0, 9999):04d}\n")
```

Comment: Can I ask for help again, how to save the results into the TXT file?

Comment: @NancySavchenko, have you tried to search for answer? Maybe read some [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)?

Comment: @NancySavchenko Added an example how to write to file

Comment: `print(..., file=f)` could be an option to not add `\n` manually.

Comment: Olvin roght I also use your advice but the code still doesn't work

Comment: @NancySavchenko, `open("your_file.txt", "w")`

Comment: Yea, the `"w"` was missing, added it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy's random generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) or the standard [random library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) below an *quick* example with numpy

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(100): 
  print("EE-0210050000484848{:04d}".format(np.random.randint(0,9999)))
```

to use the standard random library simply use `import random` and then `random.randint()` instead of the numpy function

Comment: It's also not necessary to import numpy for something that can be easily done with a built-in library...